# What is a class "in" a countable transitive model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Jech's "Set Theory" and on p235 he describes forcing with a class of conditions. He starts talking about the "classes in" a countable transitive model $M$, and I'm wondering what he means by this. My guess is that it's something like a set $X\subseteq M$, such that $V^M_\alpha \cap X \in M$ for every $\alpha$. Or perhaps it's more demanding: a subset of $M$ definable from parameters in $M$? Assuming it's one of these, is there something wrong with the other notion class for the purposes of class forcing?

Comment: Unless he says otherwise, it's the latter: "class" in set theory almost always means "definable-with-parameters subset (in the model-theoretic sense) of the model in question."

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is the other notion a reasonable thing to mean? Is it possible to do forcing with a class in the former sense?

Comment: I think it’s better to say “a class of a transitive model $M$ of ZFC”, rather than “a class in ….”  In this context the preposition “in” would mean that the class belongs to the model, which isn’t correct. (A proper class is a subset but not a member of the model.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector I agree but Jech uses "in". I'm not sure I understand your second point: there will be sets of naturals that are subsets of a c.t.m. M that are not in M, but we wouldn't call those proper classes.

Comment: I understand that Jech uses “in”, so the phrasing in your question was certainly appropriate. For the second part, I was just saying that “in” wasn’t right because it means (in this context) “is a member of”, which doesn’t apply to a proper class of $M.$  [The whole thing was just a minor linguistic comment, not a critique.]

Comment: @MitchellSpector Got it! Yes, using "in" in this context is strange.